# Streamlit : How to reload a page using a button and storing previous informations after each click

Tags: python, streamlit

The aim of my application is to build a (downloadable) tsv file after filling a form. Each form page is related to a new student's information. So I always have the same page structure (same form for each student). What I want is adding a button that generates a new page for each new student. At the end, an "end" button should display the Table (using for instance `st.dataframe()`) of all students.

The following script generates one single page (toy example):

```py
import streamlit as st
class NewStudent():
    def __init__(self, page_id):
        st.title(f"Student N°{page_id}")
        self.name = st.text_input("Name")
        self.age = st.text_input("Age")
    
new_student = NewStudent(page_id=1)
```

I've been testing many solutions, but all the solutions add an NewStudent in the same page.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Create a loop to process student info. All info will be saved in a list which will be converted to a dataframe later.

**Code**

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


if 'num' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.num = 1
if 'data' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.data = []


class NewStudent:
    def __init__(self, page_id):
        st.title(f"Student N°{page_id}")
        self.name = st.text_input("Name")
        self.age = st.text_input("Age")
    

def main():
    placeholder = st.empty()
    placeholder2 = st.empty()

    while True:    
        num = st.session_state.num

        if placeholder2.button('end', key=num):
            placeholder2.empty()
            df = pd.DataFrame(st.session_state.data)
            st.dataframe(df)
            break
        else:        
            with placeholder.form(key=str(num)):
                new_student = NewStudent(page_id=num)        

                if st.form_submit_button('register'):                
                    st.session_state.data.append({
                        'id': num, 'name': new_student.name, 'age': new_student.age})
                    st.session_state.num += 1
                    placeholder.empty()
                    placeholder2.empty()
                else:
                    st.stop()

main()
```

**Output**

Fillup then press register to record info to a list of dictionary.
[image]

Fillup again.
[image]

Then press end.
[image]

Then the saved data will be displayed.

[image]