# Streamlit : How to empty sidebar in parallel with a form?

Tags: python, forms, sidebar, streamlit

Considering this question as the continuation of the question in [Streamlit : How to reload a page using a button and storing previous informations after each click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71410773/streamlit-how-to-reload-a-page-using-a-button-and-storing-previous-information/71417308#71417308), I would like to know how to empty a text input in a sidebar using the `form_submit_button`.

Thank you in advance.

(script after modification)

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


if 'num' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.num = 1
if 'data' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.data = []


class NewStudent:
    def __init__(self, page_id):
        st.title(f"Student N°{page_id}")
        self.name = st.text_input("Name")
        self.age = st.text_input("Age")
    

def main():
    placeholder = st.empty()
    placeholder2 = st.empty()
    placeholder3 = st.sidebar.empty()
    placeholder4 = st.sidebar.empty()
    level_key = 1000
    major_key = 2000

    while True:    
        num = st.session_state.num
        level = placeholder3.selectbox("Level", ["L1","L2","L3"], key=level_key)
        major = placeholder4.text_input("Major", key=major_key)
        
        if placeholder2.button('end', key=num):
            placeholder2.empty()
            df = pd.DataFrame(st.session_state.data)
            st.dataframe(df)
            break
        else:        
            with placeholder.form(key=str(num)):
                new_student = NewStudent(page_id=num)        

                if st.form_submit_button('register'):                
                    st.session_state.data.append({
                        'id': num, 'name': new_student.name, 'age': new_student.age, "level": level, "major":major})
                    st.session_state.num += 1
                    placeholder.empty()
                    placeholder2.empty()
                    placeholder3.empty()
                    placeholder4.empty()
                    level_key += 1 
                    major_key += 1 
                else:
                    st.stop()

main()
```

Comment: Where is your sidebar code?

Comment: By using your script, I finally found a way by using multiple placeholders for each input boxes (select, text, ...). However, is there no other way to gather all the element in one single placeholder and empty then at once ?